# Crystal Report Error in formula Record Selection, a datetime is required

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, report, formula, required

I have this formula in a report with a subreport:
if {cflows.cflow_dt} = {posnrpt.posn_dt} eccecc...

the report returns this error:

Error in formula  Record Selection:
'{?Pm-posnrpt.posn_dt}={cflows.cflow_dt} and
'
A date-time is required here.
Details: errorKind

The fields cflow_dt and posn_dt in the DB are datetime like YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000

I don't undenstand why this error occured?How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, {cflows.cflow_dt} is not a DateTime column. Perhaps it's a String.

If that was not the issue, then show the full expression in the record selection for the linked subreport.

Comment: How can I find the full expression in the record selection for the linked subreport.?

Comment: Right-click, edit subreport, Report, Selection Formula, Record...

Comment: hi, this is the full expression   :                                                                            {cflows.cflow_dt}={?Pm-posnrpt.posn_dt} and
{sectype.name} = "Client Asset" and
{cflows.cparty} = {?Pm-cparty.thekey} and
{cflows.comments} in ["ADJUST PRINCIPAL", "PRINCIPAL", "REPAY PRINCIPAL"] and
{facility.thekey} = {?Pm-posnrpt.facility} and
{facility_1.fac_type} = "DEBT" and
CDate({DBT_FacLine_GIC2.Treas_to})>={?Pm-posnrpt.posn_dt} and
{f_dates.expire_dt} >= {?Pm-posnrpt.posn_dt}

Comment: check the "date-time" elements are indeed date-time.

Comment: both  cflow_dt and posn_dt are datatime, Treas_to and Treas_from are date, but we have CDate in the formula